# "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: January(Ru) is not defined" Google chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-visualization

I tryed to load data in My chart diagram by model. But, I have problem.
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Январь is not defined
    at drawChart (3:120)
    at <anonymous>`

And I don't know, hot to fix this. I need to load page and with loading page load chart diagram. Data takes from model.

My source code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/JS/loader.js"></script>

<script>

        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'График заявок для службы @ViewBag.ServiceName',
                    subtitle: 'Заявления представлены для служб за каждый месяц текущего года',
                },
                bars: 'vertical',
                vAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
                colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
            };

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Месяц');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Общее');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Выполненные');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Актуальные');

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.tableStatementsModel.Count(); i++)
            {
                @: data.addRows([@Model.tableStatementsModel[i].Month.ToString(), @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].Count, @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].DoneCount, @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].TopicalCount]);
            }

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('graph-wrapper'));

            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

need to add quotes around string column values

(first array value in `addRows`, see below snippet...)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.tableStatementsModel.Count(); i++)
{
    @: data.addRows(["@Model.tableStatementsModel[i].Month.ToString()", @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].Count, @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].DoneCount, @Model.tableStatementsModel[i].TopicalCount]);
}
```